# ERROR: table name "b" specified more than once

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

I have a problem with my multiple join, with error:

```
> ERROR:  table name "b" specified more than once
```

I am trying to get data from 3 tables:

```
SELECT b.id bi, b.book_id bb, b.title bt, b.isbn bi, 
b.publisher bp, b.author ba, b.cover bc, b.catalog bca, 
b.stock bs, b.dateadded bd, b.year bye, c.name cn,c.id cid,
m.nik nik, m.name nm, m.department dept,p.borrow_id bid, p.date pdt,
p.datereturn pdr, p.status st

FROM library.borrow p,library.book, library.category
JOIN library.book b ON b.category_id=category.id
JOIN library.book b ON p.book_id=b.id
JOIN library.member m on cast (p.user_id as character varying) = m.nik
```

Comment: I see no connection to plpgsql whatsoever. This is just plain SQL. I fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, you are using the same table alias twice, which is not allowed

Use **distinct aliases**, or join to `library.book` only once, depending on your unknown requirements.

```
...
JOIN library.book b1 ON b1.category_id = category.id
JOIN library.book b2 ON b2.id = p.book_id
...
```

Adapt the rest of the query.

Also, there are no join conditions between:

```
library.borrow p, library.book, library.category
```

Remove the redundant  `library.book` and add a join condition for `library.category`.
Cross-joining three tables is almost always wrong and quickly produces a *huge* result set.

Finally the alias `c` is nowhere to be found. Your query is a mess.